# semantic web: distance between music entities and music recommendation

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena

I have a music ontology populated by music artists, releases and musics. Each artists has a similar to relation with other artists and i need to find a way to generate music recomendations. I've tought about a distance between entities. Is this the best way to generate simple recomendations? How can i do it? Im using jena. Thanks

Comment: So the similarity should be solely based on how many "isSimilarTo" relations are inbetween two artists?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) project. While it doesn't use Jena graphs as a data source, it is easy enough to populate an input for Mahout using the Jena API. Mahout provides a variety of ways to run recommendation algorithms. For any kind of collaborative filtering ("people who liked X also liked Y" kind of thing), you're also going to need some user ratings data. Getting enough data to get some initial recommendations to bootstrap your service can be a problem. However, the "is similar to" relationship by itself is unlikely to generate very high quality suggestions to your users.